# Updating computed columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, calculated-columns

I sql database and it has a table which has got five columns and two of which computed columns, the table acts as a datasource for the datagridview control. The problem I am having is that when I add a new row in the datagridview by inserting the values in the first three columns and then when I move to a new row the computed columns are still blank unless I click the save button on the binding navigator.

I want to update the row and show the computed columns as soon as I end editing it.

Thanks

Comment: sorry .. if it was unclear.. yeah its sql server

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that can be done without a roundtrip to the server.

If the computations are easy enough, you might consider a little jQuery script that updates the columns on the client.

Comment: +1 computed columns are computed only on the SQL Server - so you definitely do need a roundtrip - no way around that...

Comment: hmmm.. can you provide any link how to compute using jQuery as I dont have any idea of jQuery..

Comment: I could point you to http://api.jquery.com , but if you posted the code for your gridview, I might could give a better example

Comment: Hmm.. you want me to post the designer code ?... I've created the datagridview by dragging the table from the datasources on to the form although the table have got a relation with the other table. Like showing the orders(DGV) of a particular invoice.

Comment: I have an idea if I did it like importing the data from SQL in a datatable and bound that datatable to the gridview in this case since the datatable will contain the computed column will call its endedit function to get the value of the calculated field, then when I click the save button the datatable is copied to tableadaptermanager sent to the database, isn't this possible ?